# Getting a number of items created in a particular year in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am writing a function that returns a number of items created in a particular year in a pandas data frame where the search is made in a column ['çreation'] that has a format 2015-05-11 :

```py
def do_get_citations_per_year(data, year):
    result = tuple()
    citations = list()

    for index, row in my_ocan.iterrows():
        my_ocan['creation'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(my_ocan['creation']).year
        #print(my_ocan['creation'])
        if row['creation'] == year:
            citations.append(row['creation'])
    len_citations = len(citations)
    result=(len_citations)


    return result
```

When I run my function `print(my_ocan.get_citations_per_year(2015))` I get 0, but there are items created in 2015.

What's the problem?

Thank you and have an awesome day!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
def do_get_citations_per_year(data, year):
    result = tuple()
    citations = list()
    my_ocan['creation'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(my_ocan['creation']).year

    for index, row in my_ocan.iterrows():
        #print(my_ocan['creation'])
        if row['creation'] == year:
            citations.append(row['creation'])
    len_citations = len(citations)
    result=(len_citations)


    return result
```

Alternatively I suppose this would give you, what you are looking for:

```py
def do_get_citations_per_year(data, year):
    result = tuple()
    my_ocan['creation'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(my_ocan['creation']).year

    len_citations = len(my_ocan.loc[my_ocan["creation"]==year, "creation"])
    result=(len_citations)

    return result
```

(You don't have to iterate through all the pandas rows, just use `.loc[<condition>, <colimns_to_return>]`)